# VBA Error - Reflection.FTP.3

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I had this error pop up on exactly the 3rd line of code below. There seem to be no explanation on the Internet for this behaviour.

I'm looking at why this error came up, and fixed itself after few minutes.

```
Set Ftp = CreateObject("Reflection.FTP.3")
Ftp.Open "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "username", "password"
Ftp.SetCurrentDirectory "DirectoryName/DirectoryName/DirectoryName"
```

What was the error?

Run-time error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)':
Method 'SetCurrentDirectory' of object 'IReflectionFTP' failed

More details:

Application: Excel Macro

Language : VB (VBA)

***Is this because of a coding error? ***

Not likely. The macro has been long running and this came up for the first time.

***Is it because of a FTP service disruption? ***

May be. But logs have a recording for every second and there seems to be no outage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there is a connection problem here - maybe a timeout? I assume that your three lines of code don't execute one after another (ie the `SetCurrentDirectory` is after some more code).  This error will come up if the `Ftp` object doesn't have a valid connection that is logged in.  Change the IP for the `Open` command to an invalid one and you'll see you get the same error.

Try setting the following line of code before `SetCurrentDirectory` command.

```
    If FTP.Status = rcLoggedIn + rcConnected Then
        Ftp.SetCurrentDirectory "DirectoryName/DirectoryName/DirectoryName"
    Else
        'Error handle
    End If
```

Note, that you are late binding the object so  for it to work for you, you'll need the `If` statement to be:

`If FTP.Status = 17 Then`

Also, if it is a timeout problem then I'd set the Timeout period for the session to be longer, ie `FTP.TimeoutSession = 300`.